# jQuery copy and append a row with changes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to copy a row, change some data, then append it to the end of a table:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#show_new_rows_number").change(function(){
        var table_body = $("tbody");
        var master_row = table_body.clone().children('tr')[mr_selector];
            master_row.children('td')[0].children('input').first().name = 'type['+(rows+1)+']';
            master_row.children('td')[1].children('input').first().name = 'type['+(rows+1)+']';
    });
});
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>First Name:</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" name="first_name[1]"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="last_name[1]"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <input type="number" min=1 max=10 value=1 id="show_new_rows_number">
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm getting an error that `master_row.children is not a function`. I really stink at traversing and doing anything in Javascript when it comes to DOM manipulation. Please help! I haven't even gotten to appending the row to the table yet and already getting errors.

Comment: try this: $("body").on("change", "#show_new_rows_number", function(){ ......

Comment: What is `mr_selector`? what value does it contain?

Comment: Sorry, it always contains the value 1. I declared the value above but thought I had modified it out in my simplified code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the elements returned from the jQuery's `.children()` method, are not jQuery elements, they are HTML elements, thus they do not have any `.children()` method.

So, assuming that the rest of the code is correct (since this seems to be just a part of the javascript code), your code should be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#show_new_rows_number").change(function(){
        var table_body = $("tbody");
        var master_row = table_body.clone().children('tr')[mr_selector];
        $(master_row.children('td')[0]).children('input').first().name = 'type['+(rows+1)+']';
        $(master_row.children('td')[1]).children('input').first().name = 'type['+(rows+1)+']';
    });
});
```

O such cases, use the developer tools to print some values on the console. If you run `console.log($("tbody").clone().children('tr')[mr_selector].children('td')[0]);` you will get just a HTML element, not an jQuery element.